# Is it called 'crank'?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

[image: This tool]

The tool is used to start the engine of the tractor below. Is it called '**crank**' or something else?

[image: tool]

Comment: As far as I know, yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank_(mechanism)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is called a crank.  I remember my father using one on the farm.

it's name comes from the fact that it turns the **crank**shaft (a major part of the engine that operates the pistons).

Comment: Its name comes from the fact that *cranking* is what it does. Also what the *crankshaft* does.

Comment: In Br-Eng that would be more usually referred to as a 'starting handle'. Also anything that shape is generically called a crank - nothing to do with the fact that it engages with the crankshaft of the engine - although of course the crankshaft is so-named because it too is that shape.